# Check if the internet cannot be accessed in Python

Tags: python, exception, networking, urllib2

I have an app that makes a HTTP GET request to a particular URL on the internet. But when the network is down (say, no public wifi - or my ISP is down, or some such thing), I get the following traceback at `urllib2.urlopen`:

```
70, in get
    u = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1161, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1136, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

I want to print a friendly error to the user telling him that his network maybe down instead of this unfriendly "nodename nor servname provided" error message. Sure I can catch `URLError`, but that would catch *every* url error, not just the one related to network downtime.

I am not a purist, so even an error message like "The server example.com cannot be reached; either the server is indeed having problems or your network connection is down" would be nice. How do I go about selectively catching such errors? (For a start, if DNS resolution fails at `urllib2.urlopen`, that can be reasonably assumed as network inaccessibility? If so, how do I "catch" it in the except block?)

Comment: If I'm reading the sub-text of the question correctly, there are so many components on the trip to and from a webserver that all you can say with any certainty is that you can't get the URL. A DNS error does not imply a bad data link, it could be a DNS server failure or a port filter or just about anything. These days, given that your default router may be set to (e.g.) ignore ICMP ECHO Requests, you can't really diagnose network faults for the user from the application layer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should wrap the request in a try/except statement so that you catch the fault and then let them know.

```
try:
   u = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
   #inform them of the specific error here (based off the error code)
except URLError as e:
   #inform them of the specific error here
except Exception as e:
   #inform them that a general error has occurred
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using, except ... HTTPError should come above URLError. If you can fix this, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: But I have both URLError and HTTPError since both can occur there.

Comment: but `URLError` - being a base class - will also catch `HTTPError`. I'll edit it myself.

Answer (score 1):

[urllib2 - The Missing Manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#handling-exceptions) has a good section on how to handle URLError and HTTPError exceptions and how to differentiate the conditions that caused them.

Answer (score 1):

How about catching `URLError`, then testing the `reason` attribute? If the reason isn't one you're interested in, re-throw the `URLError` and handle it somewhere else.

Alternatively, you could try [httplib2](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/libhttplib2.html). Its `ServerNotFoundError` exception would probably suit your needs.

Comment: `reason` is an instance of `socket.gaierror` which is not found in any of pure Python library code. Trying to find it...

Comment: Here's the `socket.gaierror` documentation: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/socket.html#socket.gaierror

Comment: Problem: urlopen can also through HTTPError (`except URLError` catches it too). Not sure if it can also throw other errors.